# Landsat Level-2 products vs Landsat ARD products?

Tags: landsat

I understand that they both pre-process to give surface reflectance, but other than that I do not understand the difference.

Can anyone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

ARD is essentially a new processing level that incorporates the TOA/SR processing of Level-2, but incorporates a new Grid-Tile data format (as opposed to WRS-2 Path-Row). It also supports fetching a stack of data for a location for time-series analysis.

> U.S. Landsat ARD products are generated in the Albers Equal Area (AEA) Conic map projection, processed directly from Landsat Level-1 AEA scenes through Landsat Level-2 data products using the WGS84 datum

References:

- [Landsat Level-2 Products](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-data-products)
- [Landsat ARD Data](https://landsat.usgs.gov/ard)

Comment: please update the links